# WebBrowser access to binary content

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to access the binary data of PDFs in my C# .NET 2.0
project. I have a URL that points directly to the PDF, but I connot access the content through `DocumentStream` (which is null) . I can't use an `HttpWebRequest` to get the PDF from this URL, because the server that the PDF is hosted on requires script-based
authentication, which means I need to use a `WebBrowser` to do everything.

The authentication is no problem (I already have it logging in); I just
need to have my already logged-in WebBrowser fetch these PDFs without
any human interaction. How can I access the PDF and save it to my local disk?

This question is based on the following forum thread: http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/505986-webbrowser-access-binary-content

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the client stores logged-in state in cookies.  To send a request in a logged in state may require setting a cookie as well.  You will have to look at the browser settings (or the explicit response on the log in script) to see what to set.

(It looks like `CookieContainer` is the relevant property for `HttpWebRequest`.)

Comment: Another problem might be what is in the Accept header.  You need to make certain you accept binary content.